# Invalidating nginx cache

Tags: nginx

```
    I have cached js,css and html files using nginx to improve web page performance.

    how can i invalidate nginx cache for specific cache key?

    I have implemented like follows:
```

invalidate URl : http://localhost/invalidate_cached_url/?url=[your_url]
       -- to remove page from nginx reverse proxy cache.
        location ^~ /invalidate_cached_url/ {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            proxy_cache_purge nginx_cache $arg_url;
        }

```
when i start nginx service it is giving error "unknown directive :proxy_cache_purge".
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use free module https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_cache_purge.
Example of usage:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;

        location ~ /purge(/.*) {    
            proxy_cache_purge cache "$host$1";     
        }   

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp)$ {               
            try_files      $uri @fallback;          
        }           
    }   

    location @fallback {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /image.php?id=$1;
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```

- test.com/myimage.png - url added to cache
- test.com/**purge**/myimage.png - url removed from cache